# Getting a audio feed from my dailup modem

Tags: ruby, linux, bash, modem

My linux powered laptop still has a **dail-up modem**.

Is it possible to interface with the phone line through my modem.

Using *bash* or *ruby*, ( or something else, if I really have to) I would like to *record* and maybe even and **make** and **receive** calls.

Can this be done? and if so where do I start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a "voice" modem, then there are dedicated audio like a speaker/mic.  Otherwise, it's most likely a soft modem -- you would have to probably muck with the driver.  Not for the faint of heart, and certainly not done using bash/ruby.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall, most modems can't do this.  You need a modem with telephony (or a special telephony card) in order to get access to the actual audio.  The only interface most modems had was the serial interface, before and after the modulation and demodulation already happened.

Comment: Most modems these days are actually "softmodems", where the hardware is essentially just a soundcard attached to the phone line and an on-hook relay.  The actual modulation/demodulation is done in a software driver - so this should be possible.

Comment: @Stefan: I don't know of anything specific, just that the idea is sound.  I would suggest you start by determining if your modem driver provides a `/dev/dsp` interface to the audio.